Remove class when element focus is removed, However only works when I shift tab instead of tab to new element. (left but not right)
I have an html with some children basically a menu but 2 elements have a submenu
<div class="menu-main-menu-container">
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="header_menu">
<li id="menu-item-919" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-919"><a href="#nogo">Services</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li ...>
</ul>
<li ...<a href="#nogo">Plans</a>
<ul class="sub-menu"> ...

THe issue is when I try to remove the class active to the sub menu using JS it only works in one direction! I know menu parent selects the 2 a tags I'm trying to target for losing focus. I know menuChild accesses the child UL element.
document.querySelectorAll('.header_menu > li:has(> ul) > a').forEach((menuParent) => {
    // Find the focused menu item (the 'a' element that is focused)
    if (!menuParent) return;


    const menuChild = menuParent.closest("li").querySelector("ul.sub-menu");
    const subMenuChild = menuChild ? menuChild.querySelectorAll(":scope > li") : [];

menuParent.addEventListener('focusout', (event) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        // Check if focus has moved outside the submenu or its children
        const activeElement = document.activeElement;
        const isFocusInsideSubMenu = menuChild.contains(activeElement);

        // If focus has moved outside the submenu, close it
        if (!isFocusInsideSubMenu) {
            toggleMenu(menuChild, subMenuChild)

        }
    }, 0); // Delay to allow focusout event to complete
}, true); // Use the capture phase to catch all focus changes

The major issue is the isFocusInsideSubMenu it only goes false when I tab to left i see it in logs. Sometimes works If i click off, but it's just so inconsistent. Would honestly be fine if was broken the other way.
Update, Has something to do with my addeventlistener I just realized I need to run it on the document rather than one element!!

Please check your HTML and provide one with properly closed tags, you can also make a  snippet
